# How to generate connection strings with NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder class?

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, npgsql

I need to write a class that allows the user to specify all possible parameters of the connection string. I am working in .NET framework and PostgreSql, which is why I need the NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder class. [The documentation is kind of confusing](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.html). In the members page there are a couple dozen or so properties (Host, Port, Protocol, Database, etc.) which I assume are all the parameters which can make up a connection string. However, I don't see anywhere that explains what each of these properties means.

I was testing my Entity Framework stuff I have setup using this hard coded connection string:

```
"Server=MyComputer;Database=Context;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

How would I reproduce this connection string with NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder? There is no "Server" keyword in that list of properties. Nor is there a "MultipleActiveResultSets" keyword.

Also in terms of constructing this string builder class I mentioned... It's a bit confusing how it should be implemented. I just want a class that takes in the parameters then builds the connection string. However it seems like I have to list out all the possible properties, which is super ugly and doesn't make much sense. This is what I have so far:

```
public class PostGreSqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    private readonly NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder _connectionString;

    private readonly string _host;
    private readonly int _port;
    private readonly string _database;
    private readonly string _userName;
    private readonly string _password;
    private readonly bool _ssl;
    private readonly SslMode _sslMode;
    private readonly int _timeout;
    private readonly string _searchPath;
    private readonly bool _pooling;
    private readonly int _connectionLifeTime;
    private readonly int _minPoolSize;
    private readonly int _maxPoolSize;
    private readonly bool _syncNotification;
    private readonly int _commandTimeout;
    private readonly bool _enlist;
    private readonly bool _preloadReader;
    private readonly bool _useExtendedTypes;
    private readonly bool _integratedSecurity;
    private readonly string _applicationName;


    public PostGreSqlConnectionStringBuilder(string host, int port, string database, string username, string password, bool ssl, SslMode sslMode, int timeout, string searchPath,
        bool pooling, int connectionLifeTime, int minPoolSize, int maxPoolSize, bool syncNotification, int commandTimeout, bool enlist, bool preloadReader, bool userExtendedTypes, bool integratedSecurity, string applicationName)
    {
        // I don't have this part yet but I thought I'd just add each keyword to
        // a dictionary with its value, then construct a connection string and then
        // pass in this string to the NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder, like so:
        _connectionString = NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(string);

    }
```

Is this a ridiculous idea? The documentation is making it hard for me to understand what to do. Having two dozen parameters seems ridiculous.

Comment: Most of the properties seeem to be described in the [NpgsqlConnection](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionMembers.html) documentation. That said it's not clear why you're authoring this class. Why not use builder class directly.

Comment: Thanks for that link -- that helps a lot. Are you suggesting that whenever I need a connection string I just call new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(string)? How do I know what the string is without constructing it from the parameters?

Comment: If you wanted to use the NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder directly you could call the empty constructor, set the properties and then get the connectionstring property. Or you could just use [object initalizatoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) e.g. `string cnnString = (new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder() {Host = 127.0.0.1 , Database = MyDb}).ConnectionString;`

Comment: Ah ok I see, that makes a lot more sense, thanks!